# Deploying Shiny on Bluemix failing "missing start command"

Tags: r, twitter, shiny, ibm-cloud

Since I can not post more than two links, some are set as shortcut links

I was trying out the sample twitter analytics code from this site: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-rtwitter-app

I have done most of the steps but I'm getting an error when I push the code to bluemix using this command:

```
cf push MyNewShinyApp -b http://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git
```

The error is:

> an instance of the app crashed: missing start command
> exit status: -1, CRASHED

I also tried running using:

```
cf push MyNewShinyApp -b <github link>/heroku-buildpack-r.git -n shiny
```

But it is also failing.

Can anyone advise on what needs to be done to fix this issue?
Thank you.

Here is the log at the end:

> 2016-03-09T23:19:13.30+0800 [DEA/6]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid c24f9b36-7c4c-4a61-8b0f-f2b687f442e5
>
> 2016-03-09T23:19:26.12+0800 [API/4]      OUT App instance exited with guid c24f9b36-7c4c-4a61-8b0f-f2b687f442e5 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"c24f9b36-7c4c-4a61-8b0f-f2b687f442e5", "version"=>"f97a0d34-16a3-44a0-ad7f-5d58a5399220", "instance"=>"e46f7d6498e647c086fdff5c40277197", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"missing start command", "crash_timestamp"=>1457536766}

Comment: could you post the manifest.yml file ?

Comment: I don't see any manifest.yml file from the downloaded code.

Answer (score 0):

Check you package.json file and make sure you have

"scripts": { "start": "node app.js" }

Comment: I added "scripts": { "start": "node app.js" } to the project.json file but it is still unsuccessful in starting app

Comment: Did you have a resolution yet?

Comment: anyone who can help? I added a package.json with this line: {
  "name": "xxx123",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "runApp(\'<project name>\')"
  }
}
but still failing... same error.